# PHP: imagecreatefromgif() trims transparent pixels from GIF

Tags: php, gd

The following is bare-minimum code that shows GIF transparent pixels being trimmed when using `imagecreatefromgif`:

```
<?php
//$gif = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('input.gif')); //does the same
$gif = imagecreatefromgif('input.gif');
header ( 'Content-type:image/gif' );
imagegif($gif);
```

The [input image](http://deepcorelabs.com/projects/so/imagecreatefromgif/input.gif) is this:

[image: Transparent Padding]

I get [this output](http://deepcorelabs.com/projects/so/imagecreatefromgif/output.gif):

[image: Padding Gone]

It doesn't do it on every file though. [This logo works fine](http://deepcorelabs.com/projects/so/imagecreatefromgif/so-logo.gif) for example.

*Note: Windows displays input.gif thumbnail as trimmed transparency but opens just fine in the browser or photo viewer:*
[image]

So I'm thinking it's a difference in GIF file format or something.

Any idea why this is happening and how to troubleshoot it or fix it? (No Imagick pls)

Comment: Yes, this must be something about the image itself, I suppose. When I open your input GIF in the browser, it shows the way you want. When I save it from there, and then open it in IrfanView - then it get the “broken” version.

Comment: Manual for `imagecreatefromgif` says, _“Caution
When reading GIF files into memory, only the first frame is returned in the image resource pointer. The size of the image is not necessarily what is reported by getimagesize()”_ - so it could have something to do with that.

Comment: IrfanView also explicitly reports the image dimensions as `214 x 209  Pixels (1.02)`.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your help. It's so strange. First time I encounter this.